# Filter users: in group AND not in other group

Tags: users, search, filter

Please could you advise on how to filter a user query, so that users from Group A are included, but not if they are also in Group B?

```
{% set vnp_users = craft.users
    .group(['groupA', 'not groupB'])
    .orderBy('field desc')
    .all() %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that in one query only but I might be wrong.

Using two queries, you could do the following:

```
{# Fetch users from the group you don't want to display #}
{% set usersToExclude = craft
    .users()
    .group('groupToExclude')
    .ids() %}

{# Built an array of ids to exclude adding 'not' to it #}
{% set exclusionList = ['not'] | merge(usersToExclude) %}

{# Fetch your users excluding the one found above #}
{% set vnp_users = craft
    .users()
    .group('groupYouWant')
    .id(exclusionList).all() %}
```

Comment: Thanks Oli, though it would be nice if the group() method could take values to match as well as values to exclude.